# Need more approve votes - why, if I already can edit without it?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I often see a broken post where someone used backticks instead of indent for a block of code, or no marking at all.

I try to edit, but some already suggested edit pops up, asking to approve. I click yes, and then it says it needs more approval votes.

What sense does this make, if I have already the right to edit without need for approval? Shouldn't I be able to force-approve it or at least dismiss it and make my own edit with the same changes?

Not sure if I missed something, please correct me.

Comment: Hmm... did you miss the "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" buttons?